# Amend JOIN to filter results by list of IDs in foreign table

Tags: mysql, join

Here's my database structure:

[image: Observation recording - database structure]

The SQL statement I'm using is:

```
SELECT
     t1.Name AS Teacher_Name,
     t2.Name AS Observer_Name,
     o.Datetime AS Datetime,
     o.Type AS Type,
     o.Year_Group AS Year_Group,
     o.Class_Name AS Class_Name,
     c.Title AS Course_Name,
     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT l.Title SEPARATOR ', ') AS Focus,
     o.Achievement_Grade AS Achievement_Grade,
     o.Behaviour_Grade AS Behaviour_Grade,
     o.Teaching_Grade AS Teaching_Grade,
     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cl1.Title SEPARATOR ', ') AS Positive,
     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cl2.title SEPARATOR ', ') AS Development,
     o.Notes AS Notes
FROM observations o
LEFT JOIN teachers t1 
    ON o.Teacher_ID = t1.Teacher_ID
LEFT JOIN teachers t2 
    ON o.Observer_ID = t2.Teacher_ID
LEFT JOIN courses c 
    ON o.Course_ID = c.Course_ID
LEFT JOIN  foci f
    ON o.ID = f.Observation_ID
LEFT JOIN focus_labels l
    on f.focus_id = l.id
LEFT JOIN  criteria c1
    ON o.ID = c1.Observation_ID
LEFT JOIN criteria_labels cl1
    on c1.Criteria_ID = cl1.ID AND c1.Type = 'P'
LEFT JOIN  criteria c2
    ON o.ID = c2.Observation_ID AND c2.Type = 'D'
LEFT JOIN criteria_labels cl2
    on c2.Criteria_ID = cl2.ID
GROUP BY o.id
ORDER BY Datetime DESC
```

The data that's returned from such a resulset is:

[image: Observation Recording - List of observations results]

---

What I'm trying to achieve now is a search by *Course*.

The input I have for this is a list of IDs, so I was hoping I could use something like:

`SELECT * FROM Courses WHERE Course_ID IN (1, 2, 3, 4)`.

Obviously it isn't that straightforward though, as my `Courses` are on a JOIN:

`LEFT JOIN courses c ON o.Course_ID = c.Course_ID`.

How would I go about amending this statement to include such search functionality?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not? Just add to your query `where` statement:

```
.............................
LEFT JOIN criteria_labels cl2
    on c2.Criteria_ID = cl2.ID
WHERE o.Course_ID IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
GROUP BY o.id
ORDER BY Datetime DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for that valex. I've just attempted that now and it appears to return all rows? I've updated my original post to include the exact SQL I was attempting after seeing your answer.

Comment: DOH ignore that, I was using `AND` instead of `WHERE`. Working now, thanks valex!

Comment: You should add where to the main table not into your JOIN condition. These ways have different meaning. Try to add WHERE before GROUP in this case you strict whole rowset. If you add condition to JOIN you just strict connected table not whole rowset.

Comment: Aye, spotted that too. Thanks again.